# How to use jmeter to test django web?

Tags: python, django, testing, jmeter

django web use @login_required .when I post a login request with jmeter , I got "invalid" instead of logining success. How can I use Jmeter to test Django web.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you're suffering from [CSRF protection in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/), it means that you will not be able to log in using single [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, you will have to do what real users are doing, to wit:

- Open Login Page ([HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request)

  - Extract `csrfmiddlewaretoken` using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) (I would recommend going for [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor))
- Perform Login ([HTTP POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request). Make sure to provide earlier extracted `csrfmiddlewaretoken` value along with the credentials.

Check out [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) article to learn more about implementing correlation in JMeter in general and how to log into Django website in particular.

Comment: Much appreciated！